# Deploy 2 wars in repository using maven

Tags: maven

I have created 2 wars using maven war plugin as

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
            <execution>
                    <id>wl-war</id>  
                    <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                     <warName>war-wl</warName>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\wl</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp\wl\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
             <execution>
                    <id>jboss-war</id>  
                    <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                     <warName>war-jboss</warName>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\webapp\jboss</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp\jboss\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

When i do mvn deploy it only deploy the default  war
my requirement is to upload both 
  war-wl.war and war-jboss.war to deploy in repository

Comment: It looks you have two different source folders `src/main/webapp/wl` and `src/main/webapp/jboss` which gives me the impression that it would be the best having two maven projects where two different war's will be produces. Which will simply solve your problem.